# Read TCP Stream using C#

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to read Strings from a TCP port. 
When opening the port with Chrome, it looks like this, 
but with many more lines:

```
I_OH_ALPHA_VANE1 = 1
I_OH_ALPHA_VANE2 = 0
I_MIP_ANTI_SKID_INOP = 0
I_FIRE_APU_BOTTLE_DISCHARGE = 0
I_FIRE_TEST_APU = 0
I_OH_APU_FAULT = 0
I_FIRE_APU = 0
I_OH_APU_GEN_OFF = 0
I_OH_APU_LOW_OIL_PRESSURE = 0
I_OH_APU_MAINT = 0
I_OH_APU_OVERSPEED = 0
I_MIP_ASA_APA_1 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_APA_2 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_APR_1 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_APR_2 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_ATA_1 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_ATA_2 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_ATR_1 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_ATR_2 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_FMC_1 = 0
I_MIP_ASA_FMC_2 = 0
I_ASP_ADF_1_REC = 0
I_ASP_ADF_2_REC = 0
I_ASP2_ADF_1_REC = 0
I_ASP2_ADF_2_REC = 0
```

It's basiclly just many ASCII strings seperated by newlines. The "loading" symbol never disappears in chrome. My first goal is to get those strings and write them into a richTexBox. My current code looks like this:

```
try
{
  int x= 2048;
  TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

  tcpclnt.Connect("localhost", 8091);

  // use the ipaddress as in the server program
  Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
  stm.ReadTimeout = 2000;

  byte[] bb = new byte[x];
  int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, x);

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
  {
    richTextBox2.AppendText(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(bb[i])));
  }

  tcpclnt.Close();

}
catch ( Exception y )
{
  Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + y.StackTrace);
}
```

This works in parts. The richTextBox shows the first 30 lines or so, but about 200 more lines are missing. I tried to increase the buffer/byteArray size and timeoutTime, but after a point this does not help anymore.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

(I'm quite new to programming, please don't be too hard)

Best regards
Axel

Comment: if Chrome opens it it must be an HTTP server..?  Additionally, you say the loading symbol never goes away - does that mean this is an infinite stream, or just that the result is very large?

Comment: It might also be a HTTP I guess, the guide from the server software just says "Communication with the driver is either through the configured COM port or through the TCP
port. The driver listens on TCP port 8091 for incoming connections." (You can also write to the server, but I just need to read). It is and infite stream

Comment: You have to call `stm.Read` multiple times and concatenate results.

Comment: If this is HTTP, then I strongly recommend to use HttpWebRequest class to issue the request and get the response.

Comment: @n0rd: He wrote increasing buffer does not help.

Comment: it's not the buffer size issue. You cannot read all data in single `Read` call no matter how large buffer you give it.

Comment: I recommend you do a quick search for `c# tcp chat` sample and see how they do that.  There are TONS of tcp client samples all over the internet.

Comment: @n0rd: OK, your are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network transfers are not instant and both sending and receiving ends have underlying buffers that tend to fill up (which blocks transfers), with that in mind `stm.Read` in your code blocks until it has at least 1 byte to return, but returns only the data it had available the moment it become available. It will *not* block until passed buffer fills up. So you have to call it multiple times to read all the data.

Example:

You call `stm.Read` passing 2048 bytes buffer to it. Then server starts sending data, first chunk of 1400 bytes arrives, at this moment your read call returns, and your code continues execution, 1 ms later another chunk arrives, but now you have to call `stm.Read` again to get it.